# Create Table Structure From SQL Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**System Parameters**

- MS SQL Server Management Studio
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

**The XML FIle**

[Link To XML File](http://pastebin.com/1fYy57Ax)

**Problem**

I am having an issue getting the results of a query into their own table and structure. I get the table I want printed to the screen in the results window, but then how do I get these results into their own table? Is there a function to take the results accumulated and send them to a table of their own? Try running the code using the toy XML file I have given. You can see that the table that is created is not the same as the results that are shown in the image provided. I would like to create a table that is the same as the results from the query executed. There is an image of that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOfjs.jpg) and below.

**Things I've Tried**

- Putting all the temporary data (#tempAllData) into its own table

  - `INSERT INTO dbo.FastSpot_To_KComp SELECT * FROM #tempAllData`
- Putting all the other temporary tables into permanent tables using the same script.

**Current Results**

- [Results, and further description with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOfjs.jpg)

Thanks!

**----The Code----**

**First Query (No Problems)**

```
DECLARE @x AS XML=
(
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\path\to\xml\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);
SELECT @x;

With MyPersonCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonID
          ,p.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,p.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
          ,p.value('Biography[1]','varchar(max)') AS Biography
          ,p.value('Expertise[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expertise
          ,p.value('Image[1]','varchar(max)') AS Image
          ,p.value('Link[1]','varchar(max)') AS Link
          ,p.query('Books') AS BookNode
          ,p.query('Articles') AS ArticleNode
          --same for Papers, Artwork...
    FROM @x.nodes('/People/Person') AS A(p) 
)
,MyBooksCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS BookID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS BookYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS BookDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.BookNode.nodes('/Books/Book') A(x)  
)
,MyArticlesCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ArticleID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS ArticleYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS ArticleDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.ArticleNode.nodes('/Articles/Article') A(x)  
)
--same for Papers, Artwork...
SELECT p.*
      ,b.BookID
      ,b.BookYear
      ,b.BookDetails
      ,a.ArticleID
      ,a.ArticleYear
      ,a.ArticleDetails  
INTO #tempAllData
FROM MyPersonCTE AS p
LEFT JOIN MyBooksCTE AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
LEFT JOIN MyArticlesCTE AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID ;

--#tempAllData is now filled with all data, copied in all combination: much to much
--but DISTINCT is your friend
--in this case you'd use the PersonID as FK in all related tables

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Biography,Expertise --other fields
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,BookID,BookYear,BookDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,ArticleID,ArticleYear,ArticleDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
```

**Second Query (Problems Here)**

```
DROP TABLE #tempArticles
GO

DROP TABLE #tempBooks
GO

DROP TABLE #tempPerson
GO

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
GO

--DROP TABLE FastSpot_To_KComp;
--GO

DECLARE @x AS XML=
(
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\KenyonCompass\Import\faculty-xml.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);
SELECT @x;

With MyPersonCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonID
          ,p.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,p.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
          ,p.value('Biography[1]','varchar(max)') AS Biography
          ,p.value('Expertise[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expertise
          ,p.value('Image[1]','varchar(max)') AS Image
          ,p.value('Link[1]','varchar(max)') AS Link
          ,p.query('Books') AS BookNode
          ,p.query('Articles') AS ArticleNode
          --same for Papers, Artwork...
    FROM @x.nodes('/People/Person') AS A(p) 
)
,MyBooksCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS BookID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS BookYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS BookDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.BookNode.nodes('/Books/Book') A(x)  
)
,MyArticlesCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ArticleID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS ArticleYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS ArticleDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.ArticleNode.nodes('/Articles/Article') A(x)  
)
--same for Papers, Artwork...
SELECT p.*
      ,b.BookID
      ,b.BookYear
      ,b.BookDetails
      ,a.ArticleID
      ,a.ArticleYear
      ,a.ArticleDetails  
INTO #tempAllData
FROM MyPersonCTE AS p
LEFT JOIN MyBooksCTE AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
LEFT JOIN MyArticlesCTE AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID ;

--#tempAllData is now filled with all data, copied in all combination: much to much
--but DISTINCT is your friend
--in this case you'd use the PersonID as FK in all related tables

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Biography,Expertise --other fields
INTO #tempPerson
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,BookID,BookYear,BookDetails
INTO #tempBooks
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,ArticleID,ArticleYear,ArticleDetails
INTO #tempArticles
FROM #tempAllData;

DECLARE @columnNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',Book_'+CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM #tempBooks FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
+(SELECT DISTINCT ',Article_'+CAST(ArticleID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM #tempArticles FOR XML PATH(''));

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*
          ,''Book_''+CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,ISNULL(CAST(BookYear AS VARCHAR(4)),'''') + '' '' + BookDetails AS Data
    FROM #tempPerson AS p
    INNER JOIN #tempBooks AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.*
          ,''Article_''+CAST(ArticleID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,ISNULL(CAST(ArticleYear AS VARCHAR(4)),'''') + '' '' + ArticleDetails AS Data
    FROM #tempPerson AS p
    INNER JOIN #tempArticles AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Data) FOR ColumnName IN(' +  @columnNames + ')
) AS p;'


EXEC(@cmd);
/*
DROP TABLE #tempArticles
GO

DROP TABLE #tempBooks
GO

DROP TABLE #tempPerson
GO

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
GO
*/

--INSERT INTO dbo.FastSpot_To_KComp
--SELECT * FROM #tempAllData  
--ORDER  BY PersonID DESC;
```

Comment: Did you already use something like [SELECT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)? You can return the results of a SELECT and store them into a new table.

Comment: I am unsure how to use `SELECT INTO`. Could you give an example in an answer to the question, @AlbertoSolano ?

Comment: Google for "SELECT INTO SQL Server"

Comment: you use it in first script... `SELECT p.* .... INTO #tempAllData FROM MyPersonCTE ....`

Comment: I tried `SELECT * INTO testtable FROM #tempAllData;` at the end, and it gives the same results

Comment: so, what result you get?

Comment: http://imgur.com/neci1yE And I have added it to the question

Comment: you get an error? can you describe problem with script?

Comment: The problem with the script that I try is that #tempAllData doesn't contain all the same data as the results of my query does. #tempAllData does not even contain the same columns as the result of the query, so when I try to create a new table from #tempAllData, I am just getting the same results as before. Try running the code above using the toy XML file I have given. You can see that the table that is created is not the same as the results that are shown in the image provided.

Comment: did you drop this table before execute script?

Comment: The #tempAllData Table? I don't think that is the problem. The #tempAllData doesn't contain the data I need.

Comment: i think that is the problem, try drop table , run script and then check result...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109954/discussion-between-adam-silenko-and-jackskis).